# match a specific word within square brackets using regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a file /home/ec2-user/hosts in which there is a group called [sample_word_test] with the square brackets and I want to add an Ip address under this group using ansible playbook. I want to match [sample_word_test] using lineinfile regex expression and add Ip address under that matching group

Following is my playbook code

```
lineinfile:
    path: /home/ec2-user/hosts
    regexp: "\[.*?sample_word_test.*$\]"
    line: "{{ new_server_ip }}"
    backup: yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very simple solution is to use [ini_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html#ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files). The task below does what is requested.

```
- ini_file:
    path: /home/ec2-user/hosts
    section: sample_word_test
    option: "{{ new_server_ip }}"
    allow_no_value: yes
    backup: yes
```

For example

```
$ cat hosts
[all]
test1
test2

[sample_word_test]
192.168.1.99
```

Comment: it adds the Ip address in this format [u'12.34.56.78'] instead of 12.34.56.78

Comment: @user11549576: Works for me. I've updated my answer with the example. For your convenience, the code is also available [here](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-102/play3.yml).

Answer (score 1):

For an exact match you should use

```
^\[sample_word_test\]$
```

You need to escape the square brackets as they are used for defining character sets in regex syntax.

- `^` - matches beginning of string
- `\[` - escaped character, matches an opening bracket
- `\]` - escaped character, matches a closing bracket
- `$` - matches end of string

Comment: In the question they are escaped but not showing. I have edited the format in the question.